# Повторное срабатывание onload на img при замене картинки

Tags: javascript

Если событие `onload` уже один раз произошло, при замене `src` событие сработает еще раз?

Comment: Да.

Comment: А просто протестировать нельзя?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Докозательство](http://jsfiddle.net/nbQjT/)

Comment: нельзя было менее жестко делать ?

Comment: оксиома докозана

Answer (score 1):

Совершенно верно! Загрузкой изображения считается загрузка картинки. К слову, если картинка недоступна, событие не сработает.

```js
var onImageLoad = function() {
  document
    .getElementById('text')
    .innerHTML += '<p>Image Loaded</p>';
};

var changeImageSrc = function() {
  var rand = Math.round((Math.random() * 200));
  document
    .getElementById('image')
    .setAttribute('src', 'http://lorempixel.com/' + rand + '/' + rand);
};
```

```html
<div>
  <img id="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" onload="onImageLoad();" />
</div>
<div id="text"></div>
<a href="#" href="" onclick="changeImageSrc(); return false">Поменять src картинки</a>
```